# Can a laser beam be captured in prism?

Tags: photons, laser, refraction, mathematics

is there a way to shoot a laser at a prism (or something) and have it glow when the laser hits it?

I want to make a small box with a small hole in it.  With the prism in the box, when the laser is aimed just right and goes through the hole, I want the prism to glow (light up) as a signal that the laser is pointed correctly.

I hope this makes since.

(It doesn't have to be a "prism", it just needs to glow or light up as a signal)

Comment: Won't any semi opaque crystal do the trick?

Comment: I don't know.  I was hoping someone would tell me. :)

Comment: A photodiode and a light bulb or LED would work. Otherwise you'll have to find a phosphor that will absorb the light from the laser and the re emit in some other wavelength region.

Comment: You don't care where the laser beam goes so long as it goes thru that one hole?

Answer (score 2):

A diamond with the "ideal cut" will sparkle; this is a special form of prism. It will have other uses when your project is complete.

See http://www.diamonddoctor.com/shopcontent.asp?type=Ideal%20Cut%20Diamonds

A fluorescing material would be a less expensive choice, and is commonly used in laser labs as a simple detector.

Answer (score 0):

If your laser is near IR or UV you can buy [strips of material](http://www.thorlabs.de/NewGroupPage9.cfm?ObjectGroup_ID=296) that upconverts and glows in the visible spectrum